# Azure Event Grid works on File Share on Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have seen on forums many developers has asked MS to enable Azure Event Grid to work with "File Share" not just with the Blob Containers in Blob Storage. can someone let me know any updates on this. I am trying to create an event to kick start my ADF pipe when a file is created on a folder in Azure "Fileshare". thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DixitArora-MSFT mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ed7fed62-fcc5-42b1-bae3-0f2850c4cb5e/add-a-trigger-binding-for-azure-files?forum=AzureFunctions)

> JeffHollan from Azure Function Product team has already mentioned in
>   the GitHub discussion that they already made request to the Azure
>   Storage team but the big item here that would enable this would be
>   Azure Files supporting Azure Event Grid for 1st party events around
>   file operations.
>
> My recommendation would be to follow the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/14) for further
>   update.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation available [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview#event-sources), Azure File Storage service is still not in the list of services that send the events to Azure Event Grid at least at the time of providing this answer.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: Feedback forum no longer available!**

Here is a feature request for this functionality. Please add your votes.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20324680-add-trigger-for-azure-file-storage